# Expanding a tensor by another one with different dimensions in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have a tensor with shape `[a,b]` and another one with shape `[a,c]`, where `c<b`. I want to merge both to a tensor with the dimensions `[a, b+c]`. How would one accomplish this in TensorFlow?

Simply using `tf.concat` won't work in this case because it expects that all dimensions, except 0, to be equal:

`All dimensions except 0 must match. Input 1 has shape [a b] and doesn't match input 0 with shape [a c]`

Comment: Do you setup `axis` parameters to `-1`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? [-1, b] or tf.concat(...,axis=-1)?

Comment: i mean last one

Comment: No, I can't do this because the tensor is the input to a dense layer and hence the dimensions must be defined.

Comment: Thank you! It was actually another problem for the input of the dense layer. Your solution was right, I'm sorry. If you repost ist, I'll accept it. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code work well:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]], tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([[4, 5], [9, 10]], tf.float32)
c = tf.concat([a,b], axis=-1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(c))
```

Or this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]], np.float32)
b = np.array([[4, 5], [9, 10]], np.float32)
aph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, None])
bph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, None])
c = tf.concat([aph,bph], axis = -1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={aph: a, bph: b}))
```

Comment: This will in my case result in: ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.

Comment: This is correct answer to your topic question. May be you should reformulate it more carefully?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I've updated my question accordingly.